# アプリ内ブラウザからのPlayストア起動の方法について

Tags: android, monaca

monacaでAndroidアプリを開発していますが、、
アプリ内ブラウザからplayストアを開こうとしましたがうまくいきません。
どうやってもブラウザで立ち上がってしまいます。

var testurl = "http://test.com/test.html"
　window.open(testurl, " _system");

--test.html--

＜a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=●●●●●●●●' target="_blank"＞リンク＜/a＞

このページをChromeなど表示させて叩くと、「アプリケーションの選択」が出てきて
そこにplayストアがあり、選択すれば起動できるのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Androidでは`WebIntent`を使用して開きます。
`monaca`のプラグインリストより追加してください。

私の実装例を提示します。
私の場合はAndroid以外もサポートしているので下記のように独自の関数もありますが参考にどうぞ

```
_confirm(
    "ダウンロードページを開きますか？",
    function (results) {
        if (1 == results) {
            //Google Play StoreのURL
            var store_url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.com.bundleid";
            //Androidアプリか？
            if (isAndroid()) {
                //WebIntentプラグインが使用できるか？
                if (isSupportedPlugins()) {
                    //Android用にWebIntentを設定する。
                    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
                        {
                            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            url: store_url
                        },
                        function () { },
                        function () { }
                    );
                } else {
                    window.open(store_url, "_system");
                }
            } else if (isIOS()) {//iOSアプリか？
                //App StoreのURL
                store_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/appname/id00000000?mt=8";
                //InAppBrowserで開く
                window.open(store_url, "_system");
            } else {//それ以外
                //サポートのWebページなど
                store_url = "https://supported.web.page/";
                //InAppBrowserで開く
                window.open(store_url, "_system");
            }
        }
    },
    "インストール",
    "開く,キャンセル"
);
```